# SQL Index Query - Should I add an Index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that needs to run against a table that is in a legacy database that isn't correctly relational (as it was an after-thought by the software house) and doesn't have primary keys etc.

The problem I have is a need to return specific data from several tables but these tables are very large in size and the query can change based on the users needs.

This query is called from an Application and returns a Dataset for consumption by a .NET application.

**Query**

```
SELECT  pro.Name , pro.Pcode , pro.Addr1 , pol.B@ , pol.PolRef@ , ec.Aggregator , 
CASE WHEN ec.Notes1 = 'Click Purchase' THEN 'BOL' WHEN ec.Notes1 = 'Click' THEN 'Click' ELSE 'TopX' END 'Type' , 
pol.Create_date 'Date' , REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(pol.Create_time), 3, 0, ':')) 'Time' , 
pol.Premium, 
ben.[Delphi ID Score], 
ben.[Delphi Score 1 - 90CON] 
FROM    dbo.ic_Daprospect pro 
INNER JOIN dbo.ic_Dapolicy pol ON pol.B@ = pro.B@ AND pol.Ref@ = pro.Ref@ 
INNER JOIN dbo.ic_DP_EC ec ON ec.B@ = pol.B@ AND ec.PolRef@ = pol.PolRef@ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_FIG_BEN ben ON ben.B@ = pol.B@ AND ben.PolRef@ = pol.PolRef@ 
WHERE   dbo.RemoveSpaces(pro.Pcode) = '" & sPostcode.Replace(" ", "") & "' 
AND SUBSTRING(pol.Ref@, 1, 4) <> 'POMS' 
AND pol.B@ IN (" & sBranch & ") 
AND pol.Create_date >= dbo.Today() - " & sDayRange & ""
```

Due to the fact that the postcode can be inputted with both spaces or without I have a function that removes the spaces in the WHERE statement and subsequently dependent on what they type in the application removes the spaces there also.

The 'sBranch' Variable is just a varchar of either 0 or 1 or 3 or 0,1,3.

Created Date is basically a dbo.Today which gets todays date without the present time and then just uses a minus x number of days by which they select from the number of days within the application.

**The Issue**

The lookup itself is used in an environment where the client is needs speed (it should always be quick if it can). It can take anything from 15 seconds to 40 seconds which is FAR too long.

Due to the setup of this database the only indexing exists on B@ and PolRef@, to speed up this query is it best I apply an INDEX to the 4 columns I am searching on 'Postcode','Ref@','B@','Create_Date' ?

I understand this is a very open question but just need some guidance, and if there needs to be some more query optimisation please let me know.

Comment: Run the query in SSMS, but first click the `inlcude actual query plan` button. If SSMS tells you to add an index, add it and repeat the process. You might be advised to add another index.

Comment: At a minimum, get indexes on the fields you use for joining the tables. But the math and functions you're using in your `WHERE` clause are going to make any indexes on those fields useless. If you can clean up the input/data such that they aren't needed, you can look a some indexes.